# Change text for an SVG text on mouseover d3js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Hi I am trying to change text of an SVG text element on mouseover.
My code looks like this :

```
            svg.append("text").attr("x",x).attr("y",y).text(a+'C'+(b+1)).attr("fill","blue").attr('text-anchor',"middle").on("mouseover",function(d){
                console.log("ho ho");
            });
```

I can see the logs being printed but I am not able to change the text for svg.append("text")
Can anyone give me some hints ?

I have also put my code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cma0h6zh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inside the mouseover handler, where you `console.log("ho ho")`, d3 sets up the `this` keyword such that it points to the DOM node that received the event, i.e. `<text>` in your case.

So you can do whatever DOM-ish stuff you want with it, including wrapping it in a d3 selection and calling d3 methods on it:

```
d3.select(this)
  .attr('fill', 'red')
  .text('X')
```

Here's a [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cma0h6zh/1/)